# jQuery get the value of ahref and put it to button

Tags: jquery, button, href

i have this problem that i need to get the value of href and pass it to a button.

is this correct format of jQuery?

```
$(function() {
    var getValue = $('#theLink').getAttributeNode('onclick').value;
    $('.yt_holder').live('click', '.videoThumb4', function(){ 
    $(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({
        holderId: 'ytvideo4',
        html5: true,
        playerWidth: '520',
        autoPlay: false,
        sliding: false,
        listsliding: true,
        social: true,
        autoHide: false,
        playfirst: 0,
        playOnLoad: false,
        modestbranding: true,
        showInfo: false
    });
    });
});
```

the button was working but it only play the first video on his list.
the link of the website is here [http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php](http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/)

now the button is this.

```
<input class="videoThumb4" onClick="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" type="button" name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut" />
```

is that correct? that i need to do a onclick `http://www....` blabla?

the `<a href>` that i like to make a button is this.

```
<?php
echo '
<a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" id="link">
' . $yValue['description'] . '
</a>
';
?>
```

how can i use .each for the button {Preview}?
how can i put the value in the button just like  --when i click this href it automatically play the video? but the button it just play the first video but not the second video.
this  i want to make it like a button.

thank you for your time.

Comment: so the scenario is that you click on the link and then it plays the video that is linked is that what you want?

Comment: @user1506189: What is your question? Please be clear and concise.

Comment: @Spiritfyre: I'm trying to verify the functionality that he wants on his script. What wasn't clear with my question?

Comment: Please edit this to state exactly what the desired functionality is, and describe what errors you noticed when you tried to implement it. You're much more likely to get a reasonable answer if you ask a clear, well-defined question.

Comment: Im sorry for that.
my question here is that how can i get the value of href to put it to the button?

i want my button same like the href functions. for example when i click preview it will play the video.

Comment: If you see the link that i posted you will see that when you click the preview button it play the first list on the playlist. but on the second playlist it doesn't play anymore. it on get the firstlist.

Comment: OK I think I understood your question, and answered. In future, it's helpful to check your browser's error console when debugging html/js errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I have understood your question correctly, you want to have the 'Preview' button follow the nested anchor link when it is clicked. You can't just do this by setting the `onclick` attribute, since this specifies a script to run when an event is raised -- not a link to follow.

If the `a` link still exists, you can have the button trigger the click on the `a` link when it is clicked (you already have a handler for the `a` link click).

First, get rid of the `onClick="..."` in the button.

Then, add the following javascript code to trigger the link click.

```
$('.yt_holder').on('click', '.videoThumb4', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(e.target).is('input[type="button"]')){
        $(this).siblings("a.videoThumb4").first().click();
    }
}
```

This will bind to the 'click' event of all `.videoThumb4` elements (currently in the document or loaded in the future), check if they are html buttons, then trigger the click on the corresponding anchor link below (which is handled by your code in your question). Note `.live()` is deprecated, and you should use `.on()` as shown for similar functionality.

---

**Update**: Your new code should look something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.yt_holder').on('click', 'a.videoThumb4', function(e){
        $('.videoThumb4').ytplaylist({
            holderId: 'ytvideo4',
            html5: true,
            playerWidth: '520',
            autoPlay: false,
            sliding: false,
            listsliding: true,
            social: true,
            autoHide: false,
            playfirst: 0,
            playOnLoad: false,
            modestbranding: true,
            showInfo: false
        });
    });
    $('.yt_holder').on('click', 'input.videoThumb4', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings("a.videoThumb4").first().click();
    });
​});​
```

Comment: you got what i mean nbrooks, but i dont know where im going to put the `$(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({` is it below the `$(this).siblings` from `if statement`? im so sorry i was new in this world of programming.

Comment: seems still not playing the video. please see the link http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php

Comment: why is it so hard to write a script but when you run it its not working T_T so easy to think it was easy to create but on reality its not really easy huhuhu..... @nbooks i just copy and paste the codes. still not playing the video...

Comment: because i put this `$(function() {`?

Comment: @user1506189 That is necessary. It executes your code once the html document is ready. Your buttons still have an `onclick` in them, get rid of those.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. i upload the without `onclick` pls check

Comment: `$(function() { /* paste code here */ });` i try it --still not playing the video but when i click the link behind the Preview button it play the video.

Comment: nbrooks, i try to make it something like this `if($(e.target).is('input[type="button"].videoThumb4')){' but the firefox crush

Comment: @user1506189 Well let's try this again. I made a change to the code, try running it. Also, I suspect this `$('.videoThumb4').ytplaylist({` should probably be `$(this).ytplaylist({`, so you can try changing that as well, if the above code doesn't fix the issue

Comment: nbrooks, im almost there, now it choose video but its not playing. the `$(this).ytplaylist({` is working so its not `$('.videoThumb4').ytplaylist({` now my only proplem is that it will auto play `autoPlay: true`. thank you so much nbrooks you help me a lot. may i know what is the meaning of `$(this)` in jQuery? Also if you notice the video doesn't show all. i mean when you just click it, it show the thumb but if not it did not show.

Comment: nbrooks, OH MY GOD!!! it was perfect! what i did is that replay put this `$('a.videoThumb4').ytplaylist({` not `$(this)` now its working. THANK YOU SO MUCH nbrooks!!! IF ONLY I CAN HUG YOU AND ADD YOU ON MY FACEBOOK THAT I WILL SAY A HUNDRED TIMES THANK YOU it make me cry!!! T_T

Comment: @user1506189 no problem glad I could help. accepting my answer is thanks enough :P -- little green tick under the up/down vote buttons

Comment: it said reuires 15 reputation hehehe, im new here.

Comment: @user1506189 nope you need 15 to vote up but you can always accept, you just need to click on the faded out check mark and it turns green

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the page that you linked to. All you have to do is to get the third sibling(things are 0-indexed so we use 2) and then execute the click event on it:

```
$('.videoThumb4').click(function(){ 
    $(this).siblings()[2].click();
});
```

Comment: $(this).siblings()[2].click();
   $(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({
    holderId: 'ytvideo4',
    html5: true,
      playerWidth: '520',
    autoPlay: true,
    sliding: false,
    listsliding: true,
    social: true,
    autoHide: false,
    playfirst: 0,
    playOnLoad: false,
    modestbranding: true,
    showInfo: false
   });
  });
@Kyokasuigetsu is that correct?

Comment: @user1506189 Getting the value at an index in a jQuery object `$(...)[n]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object -- therefore you can no longer call jQuery methods (like `.click()`) on it